# Can plasmon nanoparticles be displaced by EM field’s?

Tags: material-science, plasma-physics, optical-materials, plasmon

As at specific frequencies of light, a plasmonic nanoparticle’s electron cloud will predominately shift to one part of the material, will this cause the material to shift in that direction?